# aws codepipeline / cancel currently running pipeline on new commits

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

new to codepipeline;

```
user A pushes, pipeline `run A` is starting.  

1 min. later, user B pushes, `run A` in progress, \
new pipeline `run B` is stacked pending, until `run A` is done.
```

Is it possible to configure things, so that, a running pipeline is automatically cancelled when a new run (commit) is stacked ?

'Translating' the example above : :

```
user A pushes, pipeline `run A` is starting.  

1 min. later, user B pushes, `run A` is cancelled,
`run B` starts right away
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**  CodePipeline does not have out-of-the-box execution interruption, but you could implement it yourself.

[Pipeline executions work](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/concepts-how-it-works.html#concepts-how-it-works-executions) by applying three rules:

1. Stages are locked when an execution is being processed
2. Subsequent executions wait for the stage to be unlocked
3. Waiting executions are superseded by more recent executions

Executions patiently wait their turn.  The CLI and SDK have APIs to [stop an execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-stop.html#pipelines-stop-cli) and [get info about executions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-view-cli.html).  You could implement execution interruptions yourself by running some business logic using these APIs at the start of each new execution.

Could, but should?  A 1:1 correspondence between commit and successful pipeline execution ensures you have a clean, tested rollback state at all times.

Comment: This guy from AWS is saying something completely different. https://youtu.be/YGSJMpNTSaA?t=900 I wonder where's the documentation around that "inteligent" commit selection, lmao.

Answer (score 2):

CodePipeline doesn't have a setting to enable this without writing code.

#### Addition to `buildspec.yml`

The way I implemented this was by adding this section to the `buildspec.yml` file:

```yaml
version: 0.2

# buildspec.yml

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Killing any in-progress build pipeline executions...
      - export CODEPIPELINE_PIPELINE_NAME='python-data-jobs' # TODO: update this
      - aws codepipeline list-pipeline-executions --pipeline-name $CODEPIPELINE_PIPELINE_NAME | jq -r '.pipelineExecutionSummaries[] | select(.status == "InProgress") | .pipelineExecutionId' | xargs -I {} aws codepipeline stop-pipeline-execution --pipeline-name $CODEPIPELINE_PIPELINE_NAME --pipeline-execution-id {} --abandon --reason "Killing from buildspec.yml, as next build is starting..."

# ... the rest of the phases
```

You will need to update the `export CODEPIPELINE_PIPELINE_NAME` line to have your CodePipeline's name.

#### Permissions

You'll have to add the following permissions to the execution role for your CodeBuild. You can use an Inline Policy, for example.

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "codepipeline:ListPipelineExecutions",
        "codepipeline:StopPipelineExecution"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:codepipeline:<region>:<account ID>:<pipeline name>"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Explanation and Docs

This code starts running right before your build. It fetches the IDs of all in-progress executions, if there are any, and then stops them one-by-one with the `xargs` command.

The tutorial documentation for [stopping a pipeline execution with the CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-stop.html#pipelines-stop-cli) and [associated CLI reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codepipeline/stop-pipeline-execution.html) explain the `--abandon` and `--reason` flags on the `aws codepipeline stop-pipeline-execution` command. Note that you may want to turn off the `--abandon` flag, depending on your goals.

Note that if the kill fails (e.g., for a permissions issue), execution of the build will still continue.