# How should I deploy from staging to production when using AWS CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

We have a CodePipeline that runs on every GitHub commit/merge to the `main` branch, building the application and releasing it to a staging environment where we can manually test the application. Every now and then, ad-hoc, weekly, etc, depending on the project, we'd release to production manually. To implement this I added a `ManualApprovalStep` to my CodePipeline between staging and production but that means that my pipeline is never green. It's always stuck in blue:

[image]
[image]

This makes me think that I'm using the wrong tool here.

My mental model is coming from Heroku (ignore the review apps, I'm not tackling that challenge yet):

[image]

In Heroku there's a Tests tab that's green if the tests pass and there's a pipeline that's green if it gets deployed to staging. Lack of promotion to production in Heroku is not a non-green state in Heroku but it would be in `ManualApprovalStep`.

Is there another tool that AWS gives me to model this way of working that I'm missing?

**Update**: another big difference. The `ManualApprovalStep` seems to pile each change and releasing each change, one by one, not releasing whatever was the last release to staging, so clearly it's not analogous to the release to production that Heroku has.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that the `ManualApprovalStep` is not a natural "promotion" mechanism. They are for yes-no approvals and will result in [execution failure if rejected or after 7 days](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/approvals.html).  [Disabled Stage Transitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/transitions.html) also sit awkwardly with your use case.

`pipeline.CodePipline` executions are (a) triggered on a change to a source and (b) meant to run all stages from start-to-finish. Executions are [hard to interrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70595040/aws-codepipeline-cancel-currently-running-pipeline-on-new-commits). A consequence of a requirement to deploy environments independently is that environments are best modelled as independent pipelines, not stages within a single pipeline.

##### Simple Option: 2 github branches, 2 Pipelines

Clone your pipeline setup. A staging pipeline is tied to a `staging` branch source. A prod pipeline is triggered on changes to the `main` branch. This setup is easy to reason about and has the advantage that deploys always match your source. But it does not replicate the Heroku "promotion" concept.

##### Complex Option: 1 github branch, 2 Pipeline?

You could probably get something closer to the "promotion" pattern by having a `pipelines.CodePipeline` deployment for staging (tied to github) and a separate `codepipeline.Pipeline` pipeline for prod. The latter can be triggered by EventBridge events. Asset handling would be complex in this scenario.

##### [Edit:] Amplify CI/CD for the Front-end, CodePipeline for Back-end

[AWS Amplify CI/CD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/multi-environments.html) gives you automatic feature branch deploys, PR review approvals etc. for front-end apps.  Manual deploys require a workaround, but are possible.  See this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013908/an-aws-ci-cd-pipeline-that-allows-manual-deploy-by-commit/71019027#71019027).  The [CDK supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-amplify-alpha-readme.html) Amplify build configurations.  The catch is that these CI/CD goodies work for front-end apps, but not for arbitrary infrastructure stacks.  To get the best of both worlds, split the app in two.  Use Amplify for the high-velocity front-end and stick with CodePipeline for the back-end deploys.

Comment: I'm happy to use the two branches. I'm still having a bit of trouble modelling it due to the  fact that both branches have the same stack that's sort the main stack that deploys two pipelines which build and deploy each branch. I'm not 100% sure if the self update branch is crossing to the other pipeline. Running some experiments. It also feels like it got a bit too complex for how common this should be (and how complex it would get with review apps).

Comment: @pupeno AWS Amplify has out-of-the-box support for PR review apps and feature branch auto-deploys.  These CI/CD features are for front-end apps, though, not arbitrary CloudFormation stacks.  I added an Amplify option to the answer.  If your deployments have a front-end component, this option might make sense.

Comment: I have both front end and back end applications. I'm just working with the front end ones at the moment because they are simpler.