# An AWS CI/CD Pipeline that allows manual deploy by commit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-codepipeline

### Background

I want to create the following CI/CD flow in AWS and Github, for a react app using Amplify:

1. A single `main` branch, with short-lived feature branches and PRs into `main`.
2. Each PR triggers its own test environment in Amplify, with its own temporary subdomain, which gets torn down when the PR is merged, as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/automatically-create-and-delete-custom-sub-domains-for-your-branch-deployments-with-amplify-console/).
3. Merging into `main` does *not* automatically trigger a deploy to production.
4. Instead, there is a separate mechanism (a web page, or amplify command, or even triggers based on git tags) for manually selecting a commit from `main` to deploy to production.

### Questions

It's not clear to me if...

1. Support for this flow is already built into Amplify (based on the docs I've read, I think the answer is "no", but I'm not sure).
2. Support for this flow is already built into AWS CodePipeline, or if it can be configured there.
3. There is another AWS tool that solves this.

I'm looking for answers to those questions, or specific references in the docs which address them.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I don't think there is any easy way to meet your requirement.

If you are using Gitlab, you can try Gitlab Review Apps to achieve that (I tried before with some scripts)

Comment: What about programatically telling Amplify "take this commit SHA and release it to production"?  If just that is available, I don't mind writing a script to do the rest.

Comment: About your questions 3 and 4, I'm using CodeBuild to do the full CI/CD flow. And you can choose which branch or tag to pull. So in my opinion, if you want to build and deploy specific commit, you can make it a tag, edit the CodeBuild to pull that branch and start it

Answer (score 1):

The answers for Amplify are *Yes, Yes, Yes, Partially*.

> (1) A single main branch, with short-lived feature branches and PRs into main.

Yes.  [Feature branch deploys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/multi-environments.html).  Can define which branch patterns, such as `feature*/`, you wish to auto-deploy.

> (2) Each PR triggers its own test environment in Amplify, with its own temporary subdomain,

Yes.  [Web Previews for PRs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/pr-previews.html).  *"A web preview deploys every pull request made to your GitHub repository to a unique preview URL which is completely different from the URL your main site uses."*

> (3) Merging into main does not automatically trigger a deploy to production.

Yes.  [Disable automatic builds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html#disable-automatic-builds) on `main`.

> (4) Instead, there is a separate mechanism ... for manually selecting a commit from main to deploy to production.

Partially (`HEAD` only?).  Call the [StartJob](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/APIReference/API_StartJob.html) API to manually trigger a build from, say, Lambda.  The job type `RELEASE` starts a new job with the latest change from the specified branch.  I am not sure if `jobType: MANUAL` with a `commitId` starts a job from an arbitrary commit hash.

Another workaround for 3+4 is to [skip the build for an arbitrary commit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html#skip-build-for-a-commit).  Amplify will skip building if `[skip-cd]` appears at the end of a commit message.

Answer (score 0):

- Support for this flow is already built into Amplify (based on the docs I've read, I think the answer is "no", but I'm not sure).

*Check below links, if this help:*

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QV2WS535nyI

https://dev.to/rajandmr/deploying-react-app-using-aws-amplify-with-ci-cd-pipeline-setup-3lid

- Support for this flow is already built into AWS CodePipeline, or if it can be configured there.

*For this, you need to create a full your own pipeline. Yes, you can configure your pipeline.*

- There is another AWS tool that solves this.

*If you are okay with Jenkins, then Jenkins will help you to achieve this.
You can deploy Jenkins docker in AWS EC2 and create your pipeline. You can also use the *parameterised* option for selecting your environment and git branch.*

[image: Jenkins parameters]